# Laravel socket Get error 401 when trying to join private channel with pusher and Laravel Echo

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, websocket

I face an issue(`401 unauthorized`) while join the private channel in `laravel`. But it is perfectly working in public channel.

My **event file** is

```
class OrderUpdated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
 use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

public $new_orders;
public $user_id;
/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($orders, $user_id)
{
    $this->new_orders = $orders;
    $this->user_id = $user_id;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    //return new PrivateChannel('new_orders');
    //return new Channel('new_orders');
    return new PrivateChannel('App.User.'.$this->user_id);

}

public function broadcastWhen() {
    return isset($this->new_orders);
}

public function broadcastWith()
{

    return[
        'data' =>  $this->new_orders
    ];
}

}
```

My **`channel.php`** is

```
    Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
        // return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
        // dd("Done");

        return true;
    });
```

The **`vue.js`** is

```
Echo.private('App.User.'+this.user_id)
            .listen('OrderUpdated', (e) => {
    console.log("it is working");
 })
```

My **`bootstrap` file** look like

```
 window.Echo = new Echo({
 broadcaster: 'pusher',
 key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
 appId : '879003',
 wsHost: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_HOST,
 wsPort: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_PORT,
 disableStats: true,
 auth:{
   headers:{
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'Content-Type':'application/json',

    }
   },
  authEndpoint: 'http://192.168.11.17:8000/broadcasting/auth'


});
```

I setup my socket using [link](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/) . I already tried many solution on stackoverflow. But my issue still alive

```
Laravel : 5.8
```

Any help is much appreciative

Comment: In your vue.js file did you test the `this.user_id` is actually defined?

Comment: Yes. props: ['user_id'],

Comment: In my browser console, show like socket_id : 408720425.966832306
channel_name:private-App.User.1

Comment: Ok. I would probably dig into the vendor code that throws the 401 unauthorized and see what why it is denying access. You could simply make dd()'s in the vendor code and rollback after debugging.

Comment: Can you provide the location for the vendor code broadcasting..??

Comment: I get always like message:Unauthenticated

Comment: Unauthenticated could also be sent from Pusher. Have you checked contents of `process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY`? And where is the 401 unauthorized shown? Will you send screendump from your network tab in your browser?

Comment: Thanks for responding. My issue is resolved. The solution is I mentioned on answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue is resolved by removing some lines from bootstrap.js

```
auth:{
headers:{
'Accept':'application/json',
'Content-Type':'application/json',

}
},
```

Thankyou